# Why this Knapsack problem's solution is not working?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I was recently solving a knapsack problem. In this version of knapsack, instead of weight, value is taken into the state.

The problem is the same as general Knapsack: There are n items, Item i has a weight of wi and a value of vi. The capacity of the knapsack is W. Find the maximum possible sum of the values of items that can be filled in the knapsack.

Constraints:   1<= n <=100    1<= W <=10^9  1<= wi <=W     1<= vi <=1000

Input: n W
w1 v1    w2 v2     w3 v3   ..... wn vn

Due to large value of weight, We have to take value in the state and the result will be the minimum weight. Although I have explained the problem but in case you need more details [this is the problem link.](https://atcoder.jp/contests/dp/tasks/dp_e)

The below code is my attempt to solve the problem. I have used 1-based indexing. I'm not able to find out the error. I have tried debugging the code but that didn't help. I'm stuck on this from 2 days. Please help.

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <limits.h>
  using namespace std;

  int main()
  {
    int n,W;

    cin>>n>>W;    // no. of elements and maxm. Weight
    int v[n+1],w[n+1];   // array for value and weight 
    int dp[n+1][100001];  // dp array with size n+1 and 10^5+1 (for v max value 1000, and for n 100)

    // Initializing arrays

    v[0]=INT_MAX; w[0]=INT_MAX;

    for (int i = 0; i < n+1; ++i)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < 100001; ++j)
      {
        dp[i][j]=INT_MAX;      
      }
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < n+1; ++i){
      cin>>w[i]>>v[i];
    }
    
    dp[1][0]=0; // for 0 value, no value for weight
    dp[1][v[1]]=w[1]; 

    
    for (int i = 2; i < n+1; ++i) 
    {
      dp[i][0]=0;
      
      for (int j = 1; j < 100001; ++j)
      {
        dp[i][j]=dp[i-1][j]; // excluding the element

        if(j-v[i]>=1){ 
          dp[i][j]=min(dp[i][j],w[i]+dp[i-1][j-v[i]]); // min of including and excluding element
        }
      }
    }

    // to find the max value for which weight is <=W
    for(int i=100000; i>=1; i--){
      if(dp[n][i]<=W){
        cout<<i; break;
      }
    }

    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: You should add some input that you used for testing when you didn't get the result you expected. You should also say the result you got with this input and the result you expected.

Comment: BTW `int v[n+1];` where `n` is a variable is not legal C++. In C++ array sizes must be compile time constants. My compiler will not compile your code because of this error.

Comment: @john can you please look at the problem link. It has 3 testcases. My code wasn't able to give any output for this problem.

Comment: @john -- Not only will it not compile, even if it did compile, the stack memory may not be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few problems with your code:

- Max value can be 0
- weight needed to reach some value can be > `INT_MAX`
- `dp[1][v[1]]=w[1];` uneeded line
- `for (int j = 1; j < 100001; ++j)` `j` of 0 is valid weight though
- `if(j-v[i]>=1){`  same as above

Here's a fixed version:

```
 #include <iostream>
  #include <limits.h>
#define ll long long
  using namespace std;

  int main()
  {
    int n,W;

    cin>>n>>W;    // no. of elements and maxm. Weight
    ll v[n+1],w[n+1];   // array for value and weight 
    ll dp[n+1][100001];  // dp array with size n+1 and 10^5+1 (for v max value 1000, and for n 100)

    // Initializing arrays

    v[0]=1e17; w[0]=1e17;

    for (int i = 0; i < n+1; ++i)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < 100001; ++j)
      {
        dp[i][j]=INT_MAX;      
      }
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < n+1; ++i){
      cin>>w[i]>>v[i];
    }
    
    dp[0][0]=0; // for 0 value, no value for weight

    for (int i = 1; i < n+1; ++i) 
    {
      dp[i][0]=0;
      
      for (int j = 0; j < 100001; ++j)
      {
        dp[i][j]=dp[i-1][j]; // excluding the element

        if(j-v[i]>=0){ 
          dp[i][j]=min(dp[i][j],w[i]+dp[i-1][j-v[i]]); // min of including and excluding element
        }
      }
    }

    // to find the max value for which weight is <=W
    for(int i=100000; i>=0; i--){
      if(dp[n][i]<=W){
        cout<<i; break;
      }
    }

    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: It is not working for test input 3. Please see this link for test input 3. https://atcoder.jp/contests/dp/tasks/dp_e

Comment: @Lucas I submitted this code and got AC so whats not working for you? https://atcoder.jp/contests/dp/submissions/15563141

Comment: Don't know my compiler is not printing anything when I give the input 3. It always works but not for this problem.

Comment: This solution will not compile using standard C++.  At the very least you should change those VLA's to `std::vector`.  Blowing out the stack memory is another issue with those non-standard arrays.

Comment: I changed the arrays to constant sizes, i.e. v[101] w[101] dp[101][100001]. But that too didn't worked. There is no output.

Comment: @Lucas -- Get rid of the hard-coded arrays.  Use `std::vector`.  I wouldn't be the least bit surprised if the issue is the stack memory.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thankyou for your suggestion. It is working:D. There's some problem I will fix them now. Can you please tell that when should I use vector instead of array.

Comment: Always use `std::vector`, unless you know that you are dealing with relatively small arrays (20 or less elements).  So if you took your original code in the post, does using vectors fix your code?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Also in case of vector should I be using constant size vectors? Thank you for your help.

Comment: just use something like this `vector<vector<long long>>dp(n+1, vector<long long>(100001, 1e17); ` you can even fill default value with vectors like this

Comment: @Photon Thank you for your answer. I have understood that dp[0][0] will be 0 but what will be the value of dp[0][i] where i is from 1 to n. Please answer. We are using 1 based indexing.

Comment: the infinity constant `1e17` because we will never update `dp[0][i]` besides initial `dp[0][0]`. In fact this problem can be solved using just one dimensional array like this: https://atcoder.jp/contests/dp/submissions/4256482

Comment: What would you prefer 0 based or 1 based indexing. Also from where to build intuition like you solved using 1d array @Photon

Comment: Well you can just notice/learn that you are updating some row `i` in `dp` array only by row `i-1` values and also notice that values to update are coming from the left, so by updating row in place in reverse order you will get same values just saving some space it's a well known trick in competitive programming (helps to avoid MLE too), for indexing I prefer 1 based indexing, though i'm comfortable with 0 based one too

Comment: @Lucas Vectors don't have to have constant size. One of the many advantages that vectors have over arrays.